# Is there any solution to the problem of synchronization in the below code (Flutter)?

Tags: flutter, dart, async-await, mobile-development

I'm developing an application in Flutter that uses google maps. Now I'm displaying the markers on google maps by getting the coordinates array by calling 'rh.populateStations()'. Now I also have to get the user's location by asking permission from him and then add it to the above array, then call the 'fillMarkers' function to display the markers on all these locations. Here is the code:

```
Future<Position> getUserCurrentLocation() async {
    try {
      await Geolocator.requestPermission();
    } catch (e) {
      print("Error occurred while requesting permission");
    }
    Position position = await Geolocator.getCurrentPosition();
    return position;
}

Future<void> loadData() async {

    await rh.populateStations();
    locationsToDisplay.addAll(rh.stations);
    Position position = await getUserCurrentLocation();
    print("Current location obtained: $position");

    userLoc = StopLocation(LatLng(position.latitude, position.longitude), 'My StopLocation', false, false, false, true);
    start = userLoc;
    start?.isStartingPoint = true;
    locationsToDisplay.insert(0, userLoc!);
    setState(() {
      fillMarkers();
    });
}

 @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
     loadData();
    // loadData().then((_) {
    //   setState(() {
    //     fillMarkers();
    //   });
    // });
 }
```

Now the problem is that I think because of the synchronization problem when the system asks for permission, it displays the error on the screen that 'RangeError (start): Invalid value: Only valid value is 0: 1See also: [https://flutter.dev/docs/testing/errors'](https://flutter.dev/docs/testing/errors%27). And after giving permission, the red screen disappears and the markers get displayed. Now I want to get rid of this red screen, which comes while asking permission.

What I think the problem is that the fillmarkers function is getting called when there is no data fetched, so that's why it is giving the error (may be I'm wrong). So please help me solve this problem.

Comment: Please confirm if the cause of the error is due to fill_marker having no data by adding dummy data. If that is the issue, set a default value.

Comment: rh.populateStations() is this method Future?  also if you share error log or screenshot will be helpfull.

Comment: @khoi No sir fill_marker is just using the data of the 'locationsToDisplay' array to return the array of Markers. The only problem causing this situation is asking user permission because if my load data is simply this:
```
await rh.populateStations();
locationsToDisplay.addAll(rh.stations);
setState(() {
      fillMarkers();
});
```
Then this will work fine

Comment: @mageshmagi Yes sir it is.

Comment: @Huzaifa if you think getUserCurrentLocation() is what causing the error then use some  isLoading flag to tackle it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
bool isLoading=false;

Future<Position> getUserCurrentLocation() async {
// get user position
}

Future<void> loadData() async {
// init loading flag to true
setState(() {
  isLoading=true;
});
// load all data
// change loading flag to false
setState(() {
  isLoading=false;
});
}

@override
 void initState() {
  super.initState();
  loadData();    
 }
@override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {     
  return isLoading? CircularProgressIndicator():YOURWIDGET;
 }
```

by doing this you can avoid, if any widget try to access the array before it is initialised